# Python-Django: save seen items in order to not show them again?

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have a site that gives you random jokes, and the problem is that sometimes it shows the same joke too often. I have a Joke model, and I want to save the ids of these jokes and for every visitor make sure that the same joke is not shown for, let's say, 20 rounds. But how can I save such data and pass them around?
Here are my views:

```
def random_good_joke_page(request):
    """If asked for a random joke, redirect to joke's page."""
    return redirect('/jokes/%d/' % Joke.find_joke("Hot").id)


def random_cold_joke_page(request):
    """If asked for a random joke, redirect to joke's page."""
    return redirect('/jokes/%d/' % Joke.find_joke("Cold").id)
```

Now, I need to save the ids of the jokes already shown and check the new id (given from the find_joke function, that takes a joke rating and returns a random appropriate joke), and if that joke was shown recently, pick a new id, until there is one not yet shown. How can I save these data and pass them to Django? I thought of cookies, or maybe add such functionality to the Joke model(although I don't think that would be for each visitor, but for all of them...). Is there some default practical way for such situations? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the *seen* jokes in the user's session:

```
seen_joke_ids = request.session.get('seen_joke_ids', [])
joke = Joke.objects.exclude(pk__in=seen_joke_ids).order_by('?')[0]
seen_joke_ids.append(joke.pk)
request.session['seen_joke_ids'] = seen_joke_ids[-20:]

# your logic to display/redirect
return redirect(reverse('joke', args=[joke.pk]))
```

Comment: Just one thing: how can I add another condition in the exclude? I just want to get the jokes with rating="Hot", not the rating="Cold". Except from that, thanks, I didn't now there was such a thing...

Comment: Just chain the queryset: 
`qs = Joke.objects.exclude(pk__in=seen_joke_ids).filter(rating='hot')`
or:
`qs = qs.filter(rating__in=['hot', 'semi_hot'])` etc.